# Edit out remark about Bountify

Tags: discussion, edits

A user has put [a bounty of $5 on Bountify on his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068018/5-bounty-ruby-1-9-3-memory-size-of-a-hash-or-other-object). I have no idea what Bountify is, so I am inclined to edit it out. Should I?

Comment: 1.) since the text is obviously no longer relevant, you can definitely edit it out (the question is almost a year old). 2.) I don't think we should encourage or tolerate external money-based bounties on questions at all, so I'd even edit it out if it was still current.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Oh, sorry, I didn't look at the date. It was on the top of the list so I assumed it was a new question. Someone must have edited it.

Comment: not a problem, it was on top because it got an answer (and that answer was edited).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, edit it out. It doesn't add anything to the question or help others answer it. It's just a distraction.

Try to fix the formatting issues and other things as well when you make such edits.

Answer (score 11):

Go ahead and edit it out. Even though the bounty appears to have been paid and therefore no longer relevant, we don't really want this kind of thing on our site. We already have our own bounty system which works just fine without people parting with cash for answers.

Comment: True, it's sheer advertisement to external website that got nothing to do with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's a year old it should be edited out, but I certainly don't think we should discourage users from being creative about trying to draw in good answers.  It doesn't hurt this site any, and if the poster thinks it helps him, then more power to him.  **It's all about getting the answers you need.**

Comment: A few scattered instances of this surely wouldn't hurt, you're right. I fear the Law of Unforseen Consequences here, however.